# Kafka Mongo on kubernetes(minikube) (Mongo as source to Kafka NOT Working) with bitnami/kafka

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, bitnami

**Which chart**:
charts/bitnami/kafka/
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka

**Describe the bug**
I am following the tutorial  [Build a Scalable, Fault-Tolerant Messaging Cluster on Kubernetes with Apache Kafka and MongoDB](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/build-messaging-cluster-apache-kafka-mongodb-kubernetes/)

To resolve the extraDeploy issue i followed [extraDeploy doesn't render with example in documentation #5649](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/5649). The issue is resolved and i have working configuration as below:

1. Dockerfile

```
FROM bitnami/kafka:latest

RUN mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins && \
    cd /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins && \
    curl --remote-name --location --silent https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mongodb/kafka/mongo-kafka-connect/1.6.1/mongo-kafka-connect-1.6.1-all.jar
```

2. Values.yml

```
extraDeploy:
  - |
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
      labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels: {{- include "common.labels.matchLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
          app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
      template:
        metadata:
          labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 8 }}
            app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: connect
              image: kafka-connect-bitnami:5.22
              imagePullPolicy: Never
              command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /config/connect-standalone.properties /config/mongodb-sink.properties"]
              ports:
                - name: connector
                  containerPort: 8083
              volumeMounts:
                - name: configuration
                  mountPath: /config
          volumes:
            - name: configuration
              configMap:
                name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
  - |
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
      labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
    data:
      connect-standalone.properties: |-
        bootstrap.servers={{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.{{ .Values.clusterDomain }}:{{ .Values.service.port }}
        key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter.schemas.enable=true
        value.converter.schemas.enable=true
        offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
        offset.flush.interval.ms=20000
        plugin.path=/opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins
      mongodb-source.properties: |-
        connection.uri=mongodb://user:password@mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/mydb
        name=mongo-source-connector
        topics=source-topic
        connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
        tasks.max=1
        key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter.schemas.enable=false
        value.converter.schemas.enable=false
        database=mydb
        collection=source
        batch.size=0
        change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
        pipeline=[]
        collation=
      mongodb-sink.properties: |-
        connection.uri=mongodb://user:password@mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/mydb
        name=mongo-sink-connector
        topics=sink-topic
        connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
        tasks.max=1
        key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter.schemas.enable=false
        value.converter.schemas.enable=false
        database=mydb
        collection=sink
  - |
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service    
    metadata:
      name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
      labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
    spec:
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8083
          targetPort: connector
      selector: {{- include "common.labels.matchLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
```

3. I have deployed the mongodb with replica using following tutorial [Horizontally Scale Your MongoDB Deployment with Bitnami, Kubernetes and Helm] (https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/horizontally-scale-your-mongodb-deployment-with-bitnami-kubernetes-and-helm.html)

and then i run

```
helm install kafka bitnami/kafka -f values.yml
```

I have following setup up and running for mongodb-sink-connector:

[image: kafka-mongo-setup]

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/kafka-0                         1/1     Running   1 (35h ago)   35h
pod/kafka-client                    1/1     Running   0             43h
pod/kafka-connect-669487944-gb4p7   1/1     Running   0             57m
pod/kafka-zookeeper-0               1/1     Running   0             35h
pod/mongodb-arbiter-0               1/1     Running   0             42h
pod/mongodb-client                  1/1     Running   0             41h
pod/mongodb-primary-0               2/2     Running   0             42h
pod/mongodb-secondary-0             2/2     Running   0             42h

NAME                               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kafka                      ClusterIP   10.98.236.199   <none>        9092/TCP                     35h
service/kafka-connect              ClusterIP   10.105.58.215   <none>        8083/TCP                     35h
service/kafka-headless             ClusterIP   None            <none>        9092/TCP,9093/TCP            35h
service/kafka-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.108.22.188   <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   35h
service/kafka-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   35h
service/kubernetes                 ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      14d
service/mongodb                    ClusterIP   10.96.105.153   <none>        27017/TCP,9216/TCP           42h
service/mongodb-headless           ClusterIP   None            <none>        27017/TCP                    42h

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kafka-connect   1/1     1            1           35h

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-54cff6f879   0         0         0       35h
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-59fcf7754c   0         0         0       24h
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-64c5697f54   0         0         0       21h
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-669487944    1         1         1       21h
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-66c6dd4679   0         0         0       35h
replicaset.apps/kafka-connect-84ffbffd5c   0         0         0       23h

NAME                                 READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/kafka               1/1     35h
statefulset.apps/kafka-zookeeper     1/1     35h
statefulset.apps/mongodb-arbiter     1/1     42h
statefulset.apps/mongodb-primary     1/1     42h
statefulset.apps/mongodb-secondary   1/1     42h
```

I can publish the messages to mongodb successfully with above configuration. Below are some message after successful sink on kafaka-connect pod.

```
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,476] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-mongo-sink-connector-0, groupId=connect-mongo-sink-connector] Setting offset for partition sink-topic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=3, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=0}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:818)
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,519] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,522] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:7744}] to mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,522] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:7743}] to mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,523] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2650238, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongodb-primary-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017, hosts=[mongodb-primary-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017, mongodb-secondary-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[mongodb-arbiter-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017], primary='mongodb-primary-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000002, setVersion=3, topologyVersion=null, lastWriteDate=Wed Jan 19 11:52:24 UTC 2022, lastUpdateTimeNanos=188123424943131} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2022-01-19 11:52:25,566] INFO [mongo-sink-connector|task-0] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:7745}] to mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
```

**To Reproduce**

From producer:

```
kubectl exec --tty -i kafka-client --namespace default -- kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic sink-topic  

>{"foo":"bar.....12"}  
>{"foo":"bar.....1122"}
>
```

In mongodb:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> use mydb;
rs0:PRIMARY> db.sink.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61e7fb793bb99a00505efa14"), "foo" : "bar.....12" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61e7fb9f3bb99a00505efa16"), "foo" : "bar.....1122" }
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

**Issue ?**
The problem is that this chart is working only for mongo-sink. I can not able to use mongo-source-connector to use mongodb as source with above configuration `values.yml`. **Note**, for using the mongo-source-connector, i do following change in `values.yml` file.

```
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /config/connect-standalone.properties /config/mongodb-source.properties"]
```

**Expected behavior**

(i)- Kafka Connect is working with Mongo as SINK, meaning kafka-->mongo (OK).

(ii) But, it's not working as SOURCE, meaning mongo-->kafka (NOT OK).

There is NO error in pods or any of error messages that tells kafka can not communicate with mongo.

**My Questions:**

1. If i am missing any necessary settings, what are those to achieve (ii).
2. Is it possible to run source-connector and sink-connector simulatenously to receieve the updates in kafka and to send the data from kafka. If yes, what the necessary update that are to done to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for your feedback

Comment: Why are you changing the command? Kafka Connect should be running in Distributed mode, and you issue an HTTP POST to its API for the connector config. This way, you post two configs to run both in-parallel. Secondly, I suggest using Strimzi, which offers `kind: KafkaConnect` CRD objects rather than needing to mess with ConfigMap

Comment: I see... The tutorial uses `connect-standalone`... Try using a different image that includes `confluent-hub` [such as mine](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker#extending-with-new-connectors) to install [the mongo connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that this chart is working only for mongo-sink

Because that is the only connector file you gave.

You can give multiple

```
command: 
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh 
  - /config/connect-standalone.properties 
  - /config/mongodb-source.properties
  - /config/mongodb-sink.properties
```

Note: This is not fault-tolernant or to be used in production. Instead, your command should really use `connect-distrubuted.sh`, and your connector configs can be saved as JSON files and POST-ed to the service ingress port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to run with both connectors, source and sink but still only sink is working as described earlier.  I enter the data from mongo, but its not showing up in consumer. When i start the consumer, i see only following message.

One change now i observed that when i started consumer i saw following message:
```WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-87690-1, groupId=console-consumer-87690] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {mongo-source-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)```

Comment: Here is complete command and output:
`kubectl exec --tty -i kafka-client --namespace default --  kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic mongo-source-topic --from-beginning` The console screen is showing only following and no change, when i enter the data from mongo. `[2022-01-24 08:06:07,656] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-87690-1, groupId=console-consumer-87690] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {mongo-source-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Comment: That doesn't prove the connector isn't running. Use the Connect REST API to check it. Or read the Connect pod logs. That error is suggesting the topic doesn't exist. Create it first. Then start a consumer. Or, like I said, use distributed mode and ignore the found blog post

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

`kubectl exec -it  kafka-connect-765c5c57c5-djkch -- curl http://localhost:8083/connectors
["mongo-sink-connector","mongo-source-connector"]%  `

status on kafka-connect:
`k exec -it  kafka-connect-765c5c57c5-djkch -- curl http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongo-source-connector/status
{"name":"mongo-source-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.17.0.12:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.17.0.12:8083"}],"type":"source"}%`

Comment: I observed that topic `mongo-source-topic` was not created. I checked using `kubectl exec --tty -i kafka-client --namespace default -- kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper kafka-zookeeper.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 --list`. Then i created topic and verified in list. Then started consumer. `kubectl exec --tty -i kafka-client --namespace default --  kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic mongo-source-topic --from-beginning
` . Now, i don't get any WARN. Also, there is nothing showing in consumer when i insert data in mongo

Comment: `Or, like I said, use distributed mode and ignore the found blog post` . Can you suggest any url or link for trying distributed mode ? I don't know about distributed mode.

Comment: The source connector state is RUNNING, so beyond that, my only suggestion is look at logs. I can't answer why data doesn't get sent without reproducing your environment.

Comment: Distributed mode won't magically fix this, I only suggest it as the "proper" way to run Kafka Connect at scale. I suggest using [Strimzi KafkaConnect CRD](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/using.html#assembly-kafka-connect-str). Or use a different container [like mine](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker#extending-with-new-connectors) and configure it, accordingly to download the mongo connector.